# How to add custom message to Firebase Google auth popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

How do you add custom message to Firebase Google auth popup? For the stackoverflow, there is "Before using this app, you can review stackauth.com's privacy policy and terms of service." message.

[image]

Right now I have something like:

```
const googleProvider = new app.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to customize these attributes from the **OAuth Consent Screen** page in the Google Cloud Console. This link should take you to a screen where you can choose the appropriate project:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=_

Comment: That what I was looking for! Thank you 